# How to combine Bayesian Optimization and Cross Validation

Tags: cross-validation, bayesian-optimization

I am currently using a train-validation-test split and Bayesian Optimization (BO), which is straightforward. Now, I want to transition to using 3-fold cross validation and BO (+an additional test set for final evaluation). However, I see that there are two ways to do that:

1. *BO inside cross validation*: Inside cross validation, apply BO three times, one for each foldset. The issue here is that this will create three different sets of optimal hyper-parameters (one for each foldset) and it is unclear how to combine them.
2. *Cross validation inside BO*: The entire cross-validation procedure is encapsulated inside the black box function optimized by BO. This will create one optimal set of hyper-parameters.

So, is any of the above correct?

Comment: "correct" has to be defined wrt a goal. But if your goal is to find hyperparameters that perform well out of sample, then the natural extension of BO + train/test split is your option 2. As you yourself point out, you're not sure what you would do with the outputs of 1. This might be useful, however, as a sensitivity analysis (in place of using a true validation set).